# How to update/insert to table with Leaflet.draw and CartoDB

Tags: javascript, sql, leaflet, gis, cartodb

I am attempting to create a web application using Leaflet and CartoDB. I am trying to use [this tutorial](https://carto.com/blog/read-and-write-to-cartodb-with-the-leaflet-draw-plugin/) to read and write data to a public CartoDB table.

The tutorial explains how to use a security definer to accomplish this. For whatever reason, features I create using leaflet.draw in my application are not inserted into my table. I'm still new to coding and unsure how the SQL query is actually called in my code but I've tried replicating the example source code and haven't had any luck with execution.

The goal is to allow users to create and edit their points on a map and save those points to the crowdsource database in CartoDB.

The code for my project can be viewed here: https://github.com/zrobby/crowdsource-storymap

The specific SQL query that I'm having difficulty executing is shown below and comes from the tutorial linked above.

```
    DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS leaflet_upsert_usercomments(int[], text[]);

    -- Returns a set of op,cartodb_id values where op means:
    --  deleted: -1
    --  updated: 0
    --  inserted: 1

    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION leaflet_upsert_usercomments(
    cartodb_ids integer[],
    geojsons text[])
    RETURNS TABLE(op int, cartodb_id int)

    LANGUAGE plpgsql SECURITY DEFINER
    RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
    AS $$
    DECLARE
    sql text;
    BEGIN

    sql := 'WITH n(cartodb_id,the_geom) AS (VALUES ';

    -- Iterate over the values
    FOR i in 1 .. array_upper(geojsons, 1)
    LOOP
    IF i > 1 THEN sql := sql || ','; END IF;
    sql :=sql || '('||cartodb_ids[i]||','
            || 'ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(NULLIF('''|| geojsons[i] ||''','''')),4326))';
    END LOOP;

    sql := sql || '), do_update AS ('
      || 'UPDATE leaflet_data p '
      || 'SET the_geom=n.the_geom FROM n WHERE p.cartodb_id = n.cartodb_id '
      || 'AND n.the_geom IS NOT NULL '
      || 'RETURNING p.cartodb_id ), do_delete AS ('
      || 'DELETE FROM leaflet_data p WHERE p.cartodb_id IN ('
      || 'SELECT n.cartodb_id FROM n WHERE cartodb_id >= 0 AND '
      || ' n.the_geom IS NULL ) RETURNING p.cartodb_id ), do_insert AS ('
      || 'INSERT INTO leaflet_data (the_geom)'
      || 'SELECT n.the_geom FROM n WHERE n.cartodb_id < 0 AND '
      || ' n.the_geom IS NOT NULL RETURNING cartodb_id ) '
      || 'SELECT 0,cartodb_id FROM do_update UNION ALL '
      || 'SELECT 1,cartodb_id FROM do_insert UNION ALL '
      || 'SELECT -1,cartodb_id FROM do_delete';

    RAISE DEBUG '%', sql;

    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE sql;

    END;
    $$;

    -- Grant access to the public user
    GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION leaflet_upsert_usercomments(integer[],text[]) TO publicuser;
```

Comment: Related question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/134544/in-cartodb-best-way-to-have-a-table-with-multiple-contributors

Comment: Related solution: https://github.com/radumas/crowdmap-basic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My previous answer was too hacky, and it's going to be deprecated soon.

The proper way to do this is setting up a function with SECURITY DEFINER that runs the INSERT query with the function's owner permission.

Check it here --> https://gist.github.com/ernesmb/beb25f539f8ff38bbd891e6d114ea7f4

Hope it helps!

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

There may be an easier approach, granting specific permission to the table (or columns) in use, instead of creating a complex security definer function.

As you are only trying to add points, you could use something like what's in use in this example: http://bl.ocks.org/iriberri/7d84ed35ef0b5e80555d

That is the frontend app part. For granting the adequate permission to your table, you should run the following SQL, either from the SQL panel in CARTO Editor, or via SQL API.

```
GRANT INSERT (column1, column2, ...) ON tableName TO publicuser;

GRANT USAGE ON SEQUENCE tableName_cartodb_id_seq_0 TO publicuser;
```

In case there is any error, you could debug it from the Network tab in dev tools, the sql call will return a description of the error.

After granting permission, you should be able to run INSERT queries from the frontend without authenticating your call. 
Please, be aware of the risks.

Comment: Ernesto, thank you for your reply! I had not considered an alternate approach to the security definer, but your method makes sense for the simplicity of my application. I'll follow-up soon.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with 'security definer' but there could be another method just in case someone else is interested in editing features that is using a WFS transaction protocol (WFS-T)

Example using WFS-T in OpenLayers  :
http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/wfs-protocol-transactions.html

Example using WFS-T in leaflet  : https://georepublic.info/en/blog/2012/leaflet-example-with-wfs-t/